# Why does a circle cut a torus into an annulus?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Let $\phi : S^1 \rightarrow T^2$ be an (topological. Not necessarily smooth) imbedding of the circle in the 2-torus and let $\iota : S^1 \rightarrow T^2, \theta \mapsto (\theta,0)$ be the imbedding into the first factor. How can I show that there is a homeomorphism $\psi : T^2 \rightarrow T^2$ such that $\psi \circ \iota = \phi$?  Another way to ask this is "why does $\phi$ cut the torus into an annulus?" Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: I think you assume that $\phi$ is not contractible in $T^2$ for otherwise, $T^2 \setminus \phi(S^1)$ has two components whereas $T^2 \setminus \iota(S^1)$ has just one and so can't be homeomorphic. But $\psi$ would induce such a homeomorphism.

Comment: Rolfsen, in section 2C of *Knots and Links*, classifies 1-knots in the torus basically by proving this result.  It's not a long proof, but I wouldn't call it trivial either.